# WIA - capture devices on the network

Tags: c#

I am writing code in C # and WIA use to perform scanning tasks. However, I'm having trouble capturing devices that are shared on the network. My code captures all devices that are connected directly to the machine.

```
public static List<string> GetDevices()
{
    List<string> devices = new List<string>();
    WIA.DeviceManager manager = new WIA.DeviceManager();
    foreach (WIA.DeviceInfo info in manager.DeviceInfos)
    {
        devices.Add(info.DeviceID);
    }
    return devices;
}
```

How do I read the devices that are shared on the network?